# Un-editable post: "Links to pastebin.com must be accompanied by code", but link rot happened

Tags: discussion, broken-link

Example: [How do I create tileable solid noise?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4083157/how-do-i-create-tileable-solid-noise) ([On archive.org](https://web.archive.org/web/20201219192853/https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4083157/how-do-i-create-tileable-solid-noise))

The question contains a link to *pastebin.com*. This link is already rotten away and it is unreachable even on the *archive.org*.

When editing the question, an error message is displayed notifying the editor that there must be accompanying code with the link:

> Links to pastebin.com must be accompanied by code. Please indent all code by 4 spaces using the code toolbar button or the CTRL+K keyboard shortcut. For more editing help, click the [?] toolbar icon.

Any edit to this question is impossible due to this error message.

What can we do?

Comment: This is exactly why we expect questions to be self-contained instead of relying on links to external resources.  The link having rotted away, the question is not salvageable, so it ought to be closed and deleted.

Comment: Re *"Any edit to this question is impossible"*: Doesn't that come with a qualification? As a dramatic example, what prevents defacing the question (for a while)? Can you clarify (by editing your question)?

Comment: @PeterMortensen It is impossible because any edit would contain the pastebin.com link (if we do not want to vandilze the post), but can not contain the code example there. Thus, the edit can not be posted (editor gets the error message above). Question deface is out of question, it would be vandalism. The option that editing the question with also removing the pastebin.com link, while trying to lose the least possible comprehensibility, sometimes could work (but not in the case of the example - it would only make an unclear post to yet another unclear one). See my first comment.

Comment: @peterh-ReinstateMonica Since this was a meta post directly referencing another post, I thought you were referring to the title of the referenced post: "How do I create tileable solid noise?".  I was confused since I didn't see anything that could be construed as an error message there.

Comment: Where is the error message "Links to pastebin.com must be accompanied by code" coming from, BTW? I don't see that in the linked post, and I'm not seeing anything obvious in Google (though perhaps it's something I'm missing).  Was it an older comment or something?

Comment: @M.Justin Ok, no prob. Try to edit the referenced post and you will see. If your post has a pastebin.com link, without an attached code, you get this error message and you can not post it. It is because the link-only rule.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

#### If it is a question

Then it became unclear at the point that the remote link went down.<sup>1</sup> As unclear, should be closed.

If the content (the question itself + its answers, if they exist) has no lasting value, then it should be also deleted.

#### If it is an answer

We should look at if it still has lasting value of not. If not, then depending on the circumstances, we can have the following options:

1. If the answer has negative score, and we have the privilege, then we can vote for deletion.
2. If the answer has positive score, or we don't have the privilege, then we can still vote down to put it one step closer to (1). Possibly we can also flag for mod intervention if the case is obvious.

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>At the time (2010) the link-only content rules were not yet so strict as today. Today it would be closable/deletable as link-only from the first moment. Furthermore, (in the case of pastebin.com links) it could not be even posted with the error message above.</sub>

Comment: "*it became unclear at the point that the remote link went down. As unclear, should be closed.*" ideally, the question should have been closed or edited beforehand. It didn't really become unclear *now*, it always was. It was just unclear to less people before. Even before, some might not have been able to open the link due to firewall or something else with a similar effect to deny access there.

Comment: @VLAZ Afaik at the time (2010) the link-only content rules were not yet so strict as today. But yes, today it would be closable/deletable as link-only from the first moment. Furthermore, (in the case of pastebin.com links) it could not be even posted with the error message above.

Comment: So in other words, this question and answer are obsolete and should be deleted?

Comment: @MarkRansom Well I think the example question should be deleted, yes. It has no lasting value. (Btw, the archive.org snapshots could not find the code already in 2011 - probably the OP deleted it quickly).

Comment: No, I meant *your* question.  It was a joke, kind of.

Comment: @MarkRansom No, it is editable and it has archive.org link which will remain after the deletion of the original post :-)